# Bricked my TF300T: How to re-partition internal storage to get it back?

Tags: unbricking, fastboot, partitions, twrp

I upgraded to Katkiss's Android 5.0 image. It was nice but in reading I saw I could use the F2FS file system to prevent slowdown from normal usage. So I went to format /data thinking that would give me the F2FS option (instructions were not very clear). The /data format never finished so eventually I restarted. Now it won't boot, which I expected and would just reflash my install zips, but now TWRP recovery cannot mount any directories at all.

TWRP recovery will get into a boot loop but fastboot works so I reflashed TWRP recovery and then recovery works fine. But I can't reset/wipe/mount/etc. anything from within recovery as I just get errors:

```
E:Unable to mount '/data'
E:Block device not present, cannot wipe Data.
E:Unable to mount '/data'
E:Unable to format to remove encryption.
E:Unable to mount '/system'
E:Unable to mount '/cache'
E:Unable to mount '/data'
E:Unable to mount storage.
```

I tried starting ADB sideload. It says using RAM for sideload storage and that it's starting but never starts up. ADB devices list no devices.

Anyone out there have a similar issue? Is there a way to re-partition, maybe using fastboot?

If it would just mount I think I'd just need to format and install the zip files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I could use my nandroid backup to flash system.img, etc. to overwrite what's there but it's one big .win file. So I looked up the fastboot commands anyways and stumbled on an xda thread about un-bricking TF300s where they used fastboot erase on every mount point then fastboot flashed the stock firmware blob file from Asus' support website. Ran perfectly and now I have my tablet back! So all you need is fastboot to go completely back to stock.

To get to fastboot:

1. Shutdown the tablet completely.
2. Hold the Volume Down button and the Power button at the same time.
3. Let go when you see multiple lines of text at the top left and RCK Android Wipe as options.

You are now in fastboot.

To connect using a windows PC:

1. Install Minimal ADB and Fastboot: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=42407269#post42407269
2. Install Asus Sync from Asus support website (to get the drivers).
3. Open the Minimal ADB and Fastboot shortcut to open the command prompt.
4. Connect tablet to the PC's USB.
5. The PC should start installing the drivers.
6. In the command prompt type: fastboot devices
7. You should see a bunch of letters and numbers then the word fastboot. You're connected to the tablet now.

In the command window the following commands will erase EVERYTHING from the tablet. I was already unable to use the tablet at this point so I had nothing to lose really.

> fastboot erase system
>
> fastboot erase recovery
>
> fastboot erase userdata
>
> fastboot erase boot
>
> fastboot erase misc
>
> fastboot erase cache
>
> fastboot -i 0x0B05 flash system c:\adb\TF300t\blob (this is my path -
>   your's may vary depending where you stored your blob) ((also this was
>   the first time i saw the loading bar while flashing)*
>
> fastboot -i 0x0B05 reboot

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2179874&page=19

At this point, for me, the tablet was now completely back to 100% stock like it was just purchased.